# Which traits made Ravana an evil character in Ramayana?

Tags: ravana, gyana

Apart from the story of Ravana being the cursed gatekeeper of lord Narayana , which trait made Ravana lose in the battle and morality in his life?

The insight of the question is which actions triggered the downfall of a highly knowledgeable person? Ravana was a great scholar and devotee of the Mahadeva . He got various boons and conquered the planets. Such demonstrations clearly show how accomplished Ravana was , but what made him lose to Kartivirya Arjun and Bali. Why was he so attached to the beauty of Sita if he had supreme knowledge ?

If we compare us human beings as Ravana , we see that we have traits which can give us immense success in life but still due to some reasons we lose some battles in our life just like the case of Ravana. What are these Ravana like faults we make and how can we counter them to lead a right path in our daily lives?

Comment: The only thing that made him evil was his ego, Rama depicts the opposite side.

Comment: What is ego @User29449? I mean if we commit some evil with intention is that the ego?

Comment: Assuming something that isn't my own to be my own. This includes ego over money, house, job, family, or even own body. The pure self is always untouched. The concept is a bit difficult to grasp as a lot of things are included here, but for someone who actually wants to know, a formal study of Vedanta is required. Tait. Upn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ftn4zCnheBk Manduk. Upn: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGKFTUuJppU Should answer the question of ego very well.